# Does cscope support history list recording?

Tags: vim, cscope

I use **< C-\ >C** to get the callers of one function, then I can press one number to jump to one caller.  But if I want to jump to another caller, I had to press **< C-T>** to jump back, and press < C-\ >C again to get the caller list. Does cscope support history list recording ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using VIM, you can try quick fix

**:se cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-**

Navigate next or previous result with **:cn**   **:cp**

Use **:cw** to display cscope search result.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, you can use

```
:se cscopetag
```

or

```
:lcscope ....
:lopen
```

With the latter you can even use `:lolder` and `:lnewer` to switch back and forth between previous cscope queries.

#### he cscopetag:

> If '`cscopetag`' set, the commands "`:tag`" and CTRL-] as well as "vim -t" will
>   always use `|:cstag|` instead of the default `:tag` behavior.  Effectively, by
>   setting 'cst', you will always search your cscope databases as well as your
>   tag files.  The default is off.  Examples:
>
> ```
> :set cst
> :set nocst
> ```

That way you you just

```
:tnext
:tprev
```

like always.

Alternatively, you can use

Comment: Thanks, how can I get the past cscope search lists liking sourceinsight , and store the lists .

Comment: "Liking sourceinsight" ? (huh) And store them? Erm, in the quickfix/location list issue `:w scopetags.list`...?

Comment: What I want to describe is that how can I get the past cscope search list without jump back and repeat the same cscope command. I still don't know how to do from your copied manual.

Answer (score 1):

I have no real experience with `cscope` but take a look at `:help cscopequickfix`: with this option set the `<C-\>c` results are supposed to appear in the quickfix window.