# Vim cscope show results in split buffer

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, cscope

I am looking to show the results of cscope in a split window. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989964/how-can-i-get-cscope-results-to-appear-in-a-split-window-in-gvim7) is the closet thing I found to an answerbut it doesn't explain fully how to resolve the issue.
I also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644658/how-to-search-in-vim-cscope-result-window) where in the comments section they explain how to use the cscope to get a split window. But I just get an error `No matches found for the global symbol`

I thought I would make myself clear. I want to view the cscope results like this:
[image]

Comment: You can try [quickfix][1] to show cscope result.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206985/does-cscope-support-history-list-recording/22990924#22990924

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"the results of cscope"*?

Comment: Results of cscope. For ex, when I want the places where the c symbol was used. There are around 20 results. I want to search in them

Comment: I'm confused. Is that somebody else's screenshot or something? It looks like you already know how to view the result list!

Comment: Yes. It is from another question. I have also linked to it in my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `quickfix` window for this. See `:h cscopequickfix`.

I wrote a small plugin around this that makes the experience slightly better. For example, it doesn't jump automatically to first result, it maintains the splits layouts etc.

https://github.com/ronakg/quickr-cscope.vim